# Fixed component covering footer?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a sticky cta component. I need padding on the bottom of the Main Page it's on so it doesn't cover the footer when the user reaches the end of the page.

How can I do this in the cta component itself? Or not have code all over the place (adding CSS logic on the page separate from the component) making it hard to maintain?

```
export function Page() {
  return (
    <div className={`stickyCta ? "mb-50": ""`}> //want a different solution for THIS!!
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <StickyCta /> //cta has to go before the footer, as it should be here on the desktop. Sticky for mobile only
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export function StickyCta() {
  return (
    <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 right-0">
      <h1>get mine now</>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: incorrect cta position. covering footer]

[image: Needs to add padding to page so cta can go below]

Answer (score 0):

> "How can I do this in the cta component itself?"

Even if you do that doesn't effect the `Footer` component , as your `StickyCta` is fixed and is in another layer. They both are in different layer. Changing any attributes in the `StickyCta` wont affect your `Footer`

---

**How to solve this ?**

One option would be to use padding in the `Footer` instead considering the space needed by `StickyCta`